# Fort suddently died, looking for an explanation

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I had reclaimed a fortress in a hot region, and started to dig looking for water. Then a message about the fort's death appeared. One tick, I had 7 dwarves happy digging, farming, brewing, in multiple layers of cavern, and one tick later (a looong tick, the game froze a bit) and I got the fortress death message.

I did not have a savegame since not even a season had passed.

I don't have any mods. Just ironhand tileset. After reclaiming again I've got a hidden collapse, skeleton of dwarves and a dog on upper layer, and just some bag in the lowest layer where miner was working. No cave or other !!FUN!! has been located.

I'm puzzled.

EDIT: Another collapse on level lower than I had dug. I'm puzzled and scared.

EDIT: Corpses are found "dehydrated", but dwarf was fine and a lot of booze was there.

EDIT: Dug to the collapse, seem unrelated as I found a seasonal flooding magma sea and water. Also a lot of nether-cap inside the magma sea suggest that the first winter's magma flooding has filled the cave causing the collapse somehow, maybe the first time meeting the water lake.

Comment: Could they reach the booze?

Comment: yes, they were not deithrated, and one was even brewing! Alo they died togheder, all of the sudden, that is the strangest thing

Comment: Could you have dug in a way that you created a cave-in that killed all your dwarves? It would explain the lag you experienced.

Comment: i'm actually playn the same fort, and the old room are all fine. As not a full yeas has started, there is not much to look at :)

Comment: Would it be possible for you to provide a save file?

Comment: Magma doesn't do seasonal flooding. It has been known to spawn not at equilibrium with its surroundings and therefore spill over into other areas, though. Magma flowing to the lake and cooling into unsupported obsidian could easily have caused the cave ins. As far as the dwarves go, that's still a mystery.

Answer (score 4):

If you make a copy of your save, abandon your reclaim attempt, and export historical data with Legends mode, you should be able to look up what exactly happened to your fortress. A legends viewer tool may help make this easier.

From the sound of it, there was a cave floor collapse, possibly caused by digging in the wrong spot. This usually kills the miner digging and anyone below the collapsing floor, and sometimes the cloud of dust caused by the collapse suffocates everyone nearby.

Answer (score 3):

Dwarves can [die from the heat](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/v0.31:Climate):

> In extremely hot regions (above 110°F), dwarves and livestock may die from the heat (specifically, the fat in their bodies will *melt*, causing them to bleed to death) if they remain outdoors for extended periods of time.

Remember that your embark square could have multiple biomes - it could have shown as "hot" but also contain a "scorching" biome. To be sure, press <kbd>F1</kbd>, <kbd>F2</kbd>, etc. to cycle through the different biomes before you embark.

Comment: they was all inside, especially miner didn't get out for days. Also i think that this kind of death is not immediate, and triggered all of the sudden for all dwarwes.

Comment: @lesto: Do you know what it looks like to have dwarves slowly dying from heat?  I don't.  I'm not convinced I would notice until the first died.  If the game has them all die at the same time...

Comment: They would bleed copiously first if they died of melting fat. Giant red smears would be the smoking gun. It's worth noting though that df temperature is pretty weird and being inside may or may not be any protection.